# Attachment missing in Unix mail when multiple files were attached

Tags: shell-script, mailx

I am trying to attach multiple files in Unix, which are the result of a `find` command. When I try to send the mail, the attachments are missing.

```
dir=$path
echo "Entered into $spr/sum_master"
for fil in `find $dir -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"`
do
  uFiles=`echo "$uFiles ; uuencode $fil  $fil"`
done
\($uFiles\) | mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `$uFiles` will be empty after exiting `for` loop because `for` runs subshell

Comment: what is the content of path? should it be $PATH?

Comment: path=/home/as12345/bills

Comment: @dchirikov No, loops do not run in a subshell. It's things like pipes, substitutions, etc. that introduce subshells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `uFiles` ends up containing the string `foo bar qux`, then the last line runs the command `(foo` with the arguments `bar` and `qux)`. This results in the error message `(foo: command not found` (or similar), and `mail` gets an empty input.

That's not the only problem with the script. The command that builds up the `uFiles` variable doesn't do at all what you think it does. Run `bash -x /path/to/script` to see a trace of the script, it'll give you an idea of what's happening. You're `echo`ing the `uuencode` command instead of running it. You don't need `echo` there:

```
  uFiles="$uFiles
  $(uuencode "$fil" "$fil")"
```

That will make the loop work, but it's brittle; in particular, it will break on file names containing spaces and other special characters (see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more explanations). Parsing the output of `find` is rarely the easiest way to do something. Instead, tell `find` to execute the command you want to execute.

```
find "$dir" -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec uuencode {} {} \;
```

The output of that is the concatenation of the uuencoded files that you were trying to build. You can pass it as input to `mail` directly:

```
find "$dir" -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec uuencode {} {} \; |
mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

If you want to detect potential failures of the uuencode step, you can stuff it into a variable (but beware that it might be very big):

```
attachments=$(find "$dir" -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec uuencode {} {} \;)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Error while encoding attachments, aborting."
  exit 2
fi
if [ -z "$attachments" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Notice: no files to attach, so mail not sent."
  exit 0
fi
echo "$attachments" | mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

Alternatively, write a temporary file.

```
attachments=
trap 'rm -f "$attachments"' EXIT HUP INT TERM
attachments=$(mktemp)
find "$dir" -ctime -2 -type f -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec uuencode {} {} \; >"$attachments"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Error while encoding attachments, aborting."
  exit 2
fi
if ! [ -s "$attachments" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Notice: no files to attach, so mail not sent."
  exit 0
fi
mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com <"$attachments"
```